# Value https://test.com at url of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to get the url as string by calling the method getResponseString below, but I keep getting this error.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

ERROR:

`JSONException: Value https://test.com at destinationUrl of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

JSON:

```
"{"destinationUrl":"https://www.test.com"}"
```

CODE:

```
        try {
            JSONObject responseBodyJSON = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            if (responseBodyJSON.length() < 1) {
                throw new JSONException("response empty");
            } else if (responseBodyJSON.length() == 1) {
                return responseBodyJSON.getJSONObject(responseBodyJSON.keys().next()).toString();
            } else {
                return responseBody;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
```

Comment: are you fetching the JSON from internet or from manual data? check if data is getting loaded successfully

Answer (score 0):

you can get the string directly:

```
 try {
        JSONObject responseBodyJSON = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        return responseBodyJSON.getString("destinationUrl");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    }
```

Comment: This is not helpful because it will not help with dynamic response keys from the payload/response. That's the reason of conversion to JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

I used kotlin for the solution, yan use java conversion here,Use json parser like this,

gradle :     implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

```
import org.json.simple.parser.*

var parser   = JSONParser()
val jsonTree = parser.parse(responseBody)
```

after creating json tree object you can cast to the your model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUxFJ.png)
here you can see the json tree object you can get the fields values separately.

---